# Laravel Vue - How to make vue to look for images in public folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to load images from the public folder in the vue components. The asset helper doesn't work in vue , so I need to use the format

```
<img :src="'img/ic_add-sm.svg'" >
```

But instead of looking for the images in the public folder , vue is appending the current URL to the image path. For example , if the url is www.example.com/posts

it adds www.example.com/posts/img/ic_add-sm.svg
instead of  www.example.com/img/ic_add-sm.svg

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add a forward slash to the beginning of your image path.

```
<img :src="'/img/ic_add-sm.svg'">
```

Since you don't appear to be doing anything special you should be able to just use

```
<img src="/img/ic_add-sm.svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

At first bind the value of image source

```
<img :src="getPhoto() + variableName" />
```

Then create the function under your **methods** section and simply return the directory location, that's all.

```
getPhoto(){
   
  return 'images/';

}
```

1. Note that, You cant declare directory location directly to :src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your Vue component within Laravel, you can import the image from the public folder and use it as the source for your image tag. Here's how you can do it:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="imageSrc" alt="message placeholder image" class="w-full object-cover">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import imageSrc from '/public/images/illustrations/messagenotselected.svg'
</script>
```

In this example, replace '/public/images/illustrations/messagenotselected.svg' with the path to your image. The imported image is

import src from '/public/images/illustrations/messagenotselected.svg'